# Selenium java - switch to and read xml tab

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, switch-statement

I'm working in a simple html page that contains a button that open a new tab without "!doctype", and I need to analyze it and go back to the first page

Apparently it is an html page that contains an xml, but I need another solution in Selenium.

I tried this, but I got timeout in

> webDriverInstance.switchTo().window(windowTab);

```
public void switchTab(String url) {

        try {
            for (String windowTab : webDriverInstance.getWindowHandles()) {
                webDriverInstance.switchTo().window(windowTab);

                if (webDriverInstance.getCurrentUrl().contains(url))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("Não foi possivel trocar aba", e);
        }
        setWait();
    }
```

View Page
[image]
Source page
[image: view-source]
I thought I would find the answer on this question but it was not exactly my scenario

[How to read xml embedded in the page? I want to get compare the value of exportid present in xml structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296632/how-to-read-xml-embedded-in-the-page-i-want-to-get-compare-the-value-of-exporti)

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to switch to new tab try use indexes, if you know for a fact that the tab that you open is last. You can use last flag that would switch to most recently open tab, in C# this does the trick there is also a first flag that will take you to the first tab.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

After that you would need to save the page source and parse the xml